# Virus in browser - affects chrome most of all

Tags: virus, chrome

I seem to have a virus I cannot trace on my computer, it basically rewrites pages filled with ads in the form of videos. It seems to be using AJAX here is a screenshot attached. I traced a few files and have them posted here how can I remove this virus? Where is it located on my computer?

[image]

It is writing your page too

[image]

I have some of their source I traced links will be in the comments cause I am still finding and pasting them.

At first I thought that it was writing things by latching on to source code but it is ajax from what I saw on one of their files - Also the frame src leads to a website called cliphub.tv

Comment: Ignatius - the **only** solution you can rely on here is to nuke it. There is no other way to be sure you have removed the virus. Virus removal tools can do a certain amount, and if your virus is recognised by one of them, then you may be in luck, but there are simply so many ways this could be infected that you need to just bite the bullet and start from scratch. One of the reasons questions like this are off topic here. This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40506/discussion-on-question-by-ignatius-virus-in-browser-affects-chrome-most-of-all)

Comment: Cant access chat the page was rewritten with loads of ads. How do I nuke it then?

Comment: Wipe everything. Format your drive. Reinstall from discs, clean backups etc.

Comment: Any other suggestions I have a website I am working on and I dont want to have to go through the trouble of reinstalling my server

Comment: No. That really is the only way to be sure. This is why backups are so essential. If you've never taken backups you'll see why they make sense after you rebuild your whole system.

Comment: Hmm I am going to try an adware remover.. I have not tried that as I was unsure what kind of virus I am dealing with. Although I have to get it on my phone and then transfer it cause whoever did this thought well into the issue at hand.. every site that carries ad removers or tells you how to get rid of their ads gets rewritten. Maybe it can be removed and I can save all my files in it.

Comment: Its mainly software that removes adware. So they are scared of it for some reason got to work somehow

Comment: An adware remover may remove adware. It may not. In any case, once it has finished, you still cannot be sure your machine is clean.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways such an ad-injecting malware might work and it does not even need to be installed on your system. Common ways are:

- Browser extension: there were several prominent cases where common browser extension were sold and went malicious. These probably can do anything, including manipulating data accessed by https.
- Local proxies. In this case there is a local proxy which rewrites the traffic. This is often coupled with injecting a new CA into the trust store so that https traffic can be manipulated too. Check your proxy settings. Note that it is not enough to just reset the proxy settings because usually the malware will change these again.
- Hijacked router. In this case all devices in the network are affected and https traffic is not modified (or would cause browser warnings).

But it is not clear what exactly is the reason in your case and how it can be resolved.

Comment: Browser extension is ruled out. Local proxies however I need to be looked into let me do something real quick...

Comment: Router I dont think so... let me check everyones phones but my phones personally have not been harmed.